# Error in Exported File from Data Extract activity

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have an automation which have Data Extract and then File Transfer activity. The automation run successful, file is generated on FTP but when I open the file it says "Excel found unreadable content....."

Any fix on this?

Comment: Take a screenshot of your file transfer configuration

Comment: What format is your file? I would recommend saving it as a pipe delimited file. You can use a csv, but you run the risk of of random ‘,’ breaking the columns and raising an “Invalid Field Count” error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved it was actually .zip vs .csv. When I select only one attribute for report then CSV is fine is I selected more than one for example (open and clicks) then I need to use .zip extension as system is generating two different CSV files.